# How to invoke a private constructor with JUnit / Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Since PowerMock contains an old version of Mockito, I'm trying to get rid of PowerMock and fix old tests with pure Mockito.

I am testing the class with private constructor which should not be invoked:

```
public final class Foo {
    private Foo() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Constructor should not be invoked.");
    }
}
```

It was tested using PowerMock Whitebox:

```
@Test(expected=UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public void testFoo() throws Exception {
    invokeConstructor(Foo.class, (Object[]) null);
}
```

I could not find a possibility to invoke a constructor using JUnit or Mockito without creating a new instance of a class.

Comment: Isn't a private ctor an implementation detail? Usually you don't test implementation details inside a class, but you test (at least by mocking/stubbing) the interaction between classes. So a private default ctor (without arguments) is usually used to prevent instantiation of utility classes. If there is any other ctor you could simply remove the private ctor - and it cannot be invoked anylonger. If ther is no other ctor, what would happen if this is invoked?

Comment: @cyberbrain there are no other constructors. The test ensures that the class can not be instantiated and the constructor throws exception.

Comment: If you make Foo an interface instead of a class you can delete the constructor. Deleted code doesn't hurt your test coverage.

Comment: Mockito doesn't support to mock private methods or constructors (see https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-And-Private-Methods). Also I don't see, how you could ever verify this, your test wants to see the exception, so just call the private ctor to get it? Or is the problem the mocking - or better stubbing here - of `final` classes?

Comment: @cyberbrain there is a compillation error if I just call it - "Foo() has private access".

Comment: exactly. So I still don't get what should be tested here? That no other ctor calls it? You just wrote there are none. That no static method of that class returns an instance of it? You should check the static methods to not emit an instance of that class then. So what exactly should be tested? Don't even know why the exception is thrown...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use supress method of PowerMockito:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(Foo.class));
        Foo instance = PowerMockito.newInstance(Foo.class);
    }
}
```

Note that annotations is very necessary here.

Comment: Did you read the statement of the OP "I'm trying to get rid of PowerMock" ?